# Kotlin Exposed transaction{} magic

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I've touched **Exposed** SQL framework a bit and can't find answer to a question: where **transaction{}** block obtain a DB connection from?

It's simple test

```
@Test
    fun test() {
        Database.connect({
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/foo?user=postgres&password=q1")
        })

        transaction {
            connection.isClosed()
        }
    }
```

**transaction** itself is a function

```
fun <T> transaction(db: Database? = null, statement: Transaction.() -> T): T
```

or

```
fun <T> transaction(transactionIsolation: Int, repetitionAttempts: Int, db: Database? = null, statement: Transaction.() -> T): T
```

Anyway, I don't call it with any defined args.

Could someone tell me please, where this function obtains DB from when I write

```
transaction{
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you call `Database.connect` function you define that default connection should be obtained with the value provided inside the lambda (`DriverManager.getConnection` in your case).

Comment: Hi @Tapac. Yep, I understand that. But what about **transaction**? Where does it obtain connection from?

Answer (score 1):

For those that are still interested, `transaction` obtains DB from the `TransactionManager`

You can see the code here:

https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/master/exposed-core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/transactions/ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt#L160

ThreadLocalTransactionManager holds an atomic reference to the current database:

https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/master/exposed-core/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/transactions/TransactionApi.kt#L65